# clearcanvas library c#

Tags: c#, image-processing, dicom, clearcanvas

I call the following function to set an image rendered by ClearCanvas library to a picture box. But it gives an error 
****Unable to load bilinearinterpolation.dll the specified module could not be found*** *

```
//// Code
void OpenFile()
    {
        try
        {
            LocalSopDataSource dataSource = new LocalSopDataSource(fileName);
            ImageSop imageSop = new ImageSop(dataSource);
            //IPresentationImage presentationImage =
            //    PresentationImageFactory.Create(imageSop);
            IPresentationImage theOne = null;
            foreach (IPresentationImage image in PresentationImageFactory.Create(imageSop))
            {
                theOne = image;
            }
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(500, 500);
            theOne.DrawToBitmap(bmp);

            pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
        }
        catch (Exception e2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e2.Message);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem. What I have done

1. Copy the **BilinearInterpolation.dll** (found at ClearCanvas\ReferencedAssemblies\Interpolators directory)
2. Paste the dll in the same folder where your .exe is placed.

Wow. It worked. It will work for you well.